# Debug android application

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application where I get the following exception while writing to the database:

```
An exception occurred: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException
```

But it doest say anything else(not even the stack trace).

In general I find it very difficult to debug android SDK exceptions.

Any suggestions/tips on how to debug while developing android applications?

- I am using Eclipse to develop the application.

Comment: To get the stack trace, use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse, to examine LogCat.

Comment: Are you able to run the application within Eclipse in debug mode? Should be fairly straightforward then to get at least a stack trace. Can you elaborate a bit more on what the problem is so we can help you?

Comment: If you have SQLite Exception, your query doesn't run. Get the database and try out your query in a SQLite Manager on your desktop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to learn how to Debug in Eclipse and how to use the [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) and [DDMS](https://web.archive.org/web/20120618172953/http://developer.android.com:80/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html) tools.

In order to get more details about an exception/force close you need to look for a view in Eclipse called [Logcat](https://web.archive.org/web/20100324231958/http://developer.android.com:80/intl/de/guide/developing/debug-tasks.html)(you will find in the [DDMS](https://web.archive.org/web/20170825232742/http://www.brighthub.com:80/mobile/google-android/articles/25023.aspx) perspective) there you will find a detailed traceback when/what and on what line is the issue.

For this you should read a complete article about [Debugging in Android using Eclipse](http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html)

[image]
<sub>(source: [droidnova.com](http://www.droidnova.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/debugging-3.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debug-tasks.html) question and answers, also [Developer Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debug-tasks.html).

I reckon you first get your head around handling exceptions before tackling the SQLiteException.